# Follow symlinks inside Wordpress directory?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, symlink

I'm working with a website built on WordPress, it's a fairly standard setup in cPanel. I've developed new features for the website in Laravel. I now need to view the Laravel public directory to an accessible web address.

I've tried symlinking the public Laravel directory to a directory inside public_html (where WordPress is).

I'm getting a WP 404 error, rather than the symlinked folder (Laravel public).

```
/home/user/public_html/ (WordPress DIR)
/home/user/repositories/laravel-app/public (Laravel public)
```

I then ran:

```
ln -s /home/user/repositories/laravel-app/public/ /home/user/public_html/book-online
```

I was hopeful that when going to `domain.com/book-online` it would load the Laravel app but it doesn't appear to be the case.

**Update**

I've managed to move a little further, I've realised the directory is definitely being resolved, I can access assets, just not index.php. For example. I can go to URL:

```
domain.com/book-online/css/style.css
```

and it will load the Laravel stylesheet

```
domain.com/book-online/index.php
```

gives me WordPress 404.

This is my .htaccess in public Laravel folder.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the **/repositories** folder in the symlink path "ln -s /home/user/laravel-app/public/"

Also make sure your DNS entry is set up to look for the url you need : **domain.com/book-online** in your cpanel

Comment: Unfortunately, that was just a typo, the path is definitely correct I can follow the symlink in the terminal. Apologies.

Comment: Then Wordpress is managing domain.com, therefore all pages under domain.com either are Wordpress-created pages or are 404, try adding a book-online page inside Wordpress and redirecting it to your laravel application or doing the redirect on the .htaccess file if you are using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Setting proper permissions fixed the issue.

I needed to set permissions on the public folder to 755 and also the index.php file to 644.

For others who may land here with a similar problem: First, you must symlink the public folder (or rename the public folder and move it to a publically accessible location) and set the permissions as above.